# On one class of Somos-like sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

This question is motivated by integrability of the [sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143609/does-this-sequence-always-give-an-integer/202243#202243) mistakenly arisen in the question [Does this sequence always give an integer?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143609/does-this-sequence-always-give-an-integer)

Let $m_1,\ldots, m_{k-1}$ be positive integers and sequence $\{a_n\}$ is defined by initial conditions
$$a_1=\ldots=a_k=1$$ and recurrence
$$a_{n+k}a_n=a_{n+1}^{m_1}a_{n+k-1}^{m_{k-1}}+a_{n+2}^{m_{2}}a_{n+3}^{m_{3}}\ldots a_{n+k-2}^{m_{k-2}}\quad(n\ge1).$$
Then the same (George Bergman's) argument described in David Gale's The strange and surprising saga of the Somos sequences, see [Tracking the automatic ant and other mathematical explorations](http://books.google.ru/books?id=wgVPu0YEOlQC&pg=PA1&hl=ru&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false)  allows to prove that $\{a_n\}$ is an integer sequence.

**Question**: does this sequence belong to any known class of integer sequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a special case of Case (9) in Theorem 3.9 of [Allman, Cuenca and Huang](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0751). By the way, this paper was an REU project!