# Is Somos-8 $\mod 2$ periodic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, recurrences

It is known that the [Somos-$k$ sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomosSequence.html) for $k\ge 8$ do not give integers. But the first terms of **Somos-8** sequence $s_n=a_n/b_n$
$$1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 7, 13, 25, 61, 187, 775, 5827, 14815,\frac{420514}{7}, \frac{28670773}{91}$$
defined by $s_1=s_2=s_3=s_4=s_5=s_6=s_7=s_8=1$,
$$s_{n+8}s_n=s_{n+7}s_{n+1}+s_{n+6}s_{n+2}+s_{n+5}s_{n+3}+s_{n+4}^2\qquad(n\ge1)$$
have only odd denominators $b_n$. Morever $s_n$ has even numerator $a_n$ only for $n=9k$. It was checked for $n\le 67$. First terms of  $s_n\mod 8:=a_n\cdot b_n^{-1}\mod 8$ are
$$\begin{array}{l}
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, {\bf 4},\\
7, 5, 1, 5, 3, 7, 3, 7, {\bf 6},\\
7, 7, 5, 7, 5, 3, 1, 1, {\bf 6},\\
5, 1, 5, 5, 3, 3, 7, 1, {\bf 4},\\
7, 7, 3, 3, 7, 7, 3, 1, {\bf 2},\\
1, 3, 1, 3, 7, 5, 3, 5, {\bf 2},\\
5, 7, 3, 7, 7, 3, 7, 3, {\bf 0},\\
1, 3, 7, 3,\ldots\end{array}$$

Is it possible to prove that the sequence $s_n\mod 2$ is periodic?

**EDT.** It was found by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე that numerator of $s_{71}$ is even while that of $s_{72}$ is odd. The last line of the table above is
$$1, 3, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, {\bf 2}, 5$$
So the conjecture about numerators of $s_n$ is wrong. But the qustion about periodicity is still valid.

Comment: There might be something in Robinson, Periodicity of Somos sequences, Proc Amer Math Soc 116 (1992) no. 3, 613-619, MR1140672 (93a:11012). The review by Peter Kiss says, in part, "For some sequences related to the Somos($k$) sequences, the author shows that they are periodic modulo $m$ for every $m$, although the periodicity problem remains open for the original sequences. Some observations are also made concerning the prime divisors of the terms and the rate of growth of certain sequences.

Comment: Note that if for a given $n$, exactly one of $s_{n+1},...,s_{n+7}$ is even, then both $s_{n}$ and $s_{n+8}$ must be odd. Further if $s_{n},...,s_{n+7}$ are all odd, $s_{n+8}$ must be even. So the only thing to prove is that if $s_{n}$ is even and $s_{n+1},...,s_{n+7}$ are odd, then $s_{n+8}$ must also be odd.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Robinson proved his result only for sequnces with  Laurent property. He proved periodicity of Somos-4 and Somos-5. But his method didn't work for Somos-6 and Somos-7. I don't know whether his result was extended on Somos-6 and Somos-7.

Comment: @Wolfgang Yes, the problem is in divisions by even numbers. It is not clear how can we count powers of $2$. It seems that method which work for previous Somos sequences (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143609/does-this-sequence-always-give-an-integer) fails for Somos-8

Comment: Believe it or not but actually the numerator of $s_{71}$ is even while that of $s_{72}$ is odd (unless there is a bug in Mathematica 11, that is).

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Thank you, my Mathematica gave the same result.

Comment: Doing some further calculations with 2-adics; although I am not sure I am doing it right but seems like $s_{95}$ has even *denominator*...

Comment: No it's $s_{103}$, not $s_{95}$ (the latter has even numerator)

Comment: Still have to re-check it but I switched to Pari and computed in 2-adics (with $2^{100000}$ precision), seemingly $s_{103}$ has even denominator. Up to that, results with Mathematica and Pari are identical, and also coincide with results for exact rationals (these I am currently running, they are at 82 so far).

Comment: Alas, run out of memory on 85 with exact rationals. There might be other ways to find out about parity of the denominator in $s_{103}$ though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I confirm the observation of @მამუკაჯიბლაძე that $\nu_2(s_{103})=-1$. That is, $s_n\bmod 2$ is not well-defined at first place, which invalidates the question.

Moreover, for $n\geq 133$, $\nu_2(s_n)$ seems to form a strictly decreasing function, i.e., $s_n$ accumulates larger and larger powers of $2$ in the denominators.